# The proof of existence of supremum for a non-empty set which has an upper bound

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

I was going through a simple proof written for the existence of supremum. When I tried to write a small example for the argument used in the proof, I got stuck. The proof is presented in Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra,
And Differential Forms written by Hubbard. Here is the theorem.

$\textbf{Theorem}:$ Every non-empty subset $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ that has an upper bound has a least upper bound $(sup X)$.

$\textbf{Proof}:$ Suppose we have $x \in X$ and $x \geq0$. Also, suppose $\alpha$ is a given upper bound.

If $x \neq \alpha$, then there is a first $j$ such that $j^{th}$ digit of $x$ is smaller than the $j^{th}$ of $\alpha$. Consider all the numbers in $[x,a]$ that can be written using only $j$ digits after the decimal, then all zeros.
Let $b_j$ bt the largest which is not an upper bound. Now, consider the set of numbers $[b_j,a]$ that have only $j+1$ digits after the decimal points, then all zeros.

The proof continues until getting $b$ which is not an upper bound.

Now, let's assume that $X=\{0.5, 2, 2.5, \cdots, 3.23\}$ where $3.23$ is the largest value in the set and $\alpha = 6.2$. I select $2$ as my $x$. Then, the value of $j$ is one. Hence, the set is defined as $[2.1,2.2., \cdots, 2.9,6.2]$. In this case, $b_j$ is 2.9.

If create a new set based on $b_j$, doesn't that become $[2.91,2.92., \cdots, 2.99,6.2]$. If so, $b_{j+1} = 2.99$ and I'd just add extra digits behind this number. In other words, I'd never go to the next level. I am probably misinterpreting the proof statement.

Two important details after receiving some comments are as follows.

1. "*By definition, the set of real numbers is the set of infinite decimals: expressions like 2.95765392045756..., preceded by a plus or a minus sign (in practice the plus sign is usually omitted). The number that you usually think of as 3 is the infinite decimal 3.0000... , ending in all zeroes*."
2. *"The least upper bound property of the reals is often taken as an axiom; indeed, it characterizes the real numbers, and it sits at the foundation of every theorem in calculus. However, at least with the description above of the reals, it is a theorem, not an axiom."*

Comment: How are the real numbers defined? This is important for determining how the proof will go.

Comment: Do you mean the real numbers defining set ```X```? Btw, the proof is taken from Hubbard's book on Page 7. Here is the link for the book https://notendur.hi.is/mbh6/html/_downloads/Vector%20Calculus%20-%20Hubbard.pdf

Comment: That's Theorem is precisely the *least upper bound* property.  The real numbers are constructed/defined *specifically* so that is true.  In 90% of the real analysis books you may assume that is one axiom.  In the other 10% you will *construct* the reals from scratch (often as Diedekin cuts of rational number, or as equivalence classes of cauchy sequences of rational numbers) precisely to *create* an ordered field containing the rationals with the least upper bound property which you call the real numbers. In any event you don't prove this... is is a basic fact of the reals.

Comment: No, are the real numbers defined via the set of numbers fulfilling a certain set of axioms? (Clearly not, as one axiom is the LUB property when you do it that way).  Is it via Dedekind cuts?  Equivalence classes of Cauchy Sequences?  All infinite decimal strings with the equivalence class that .9999999=1?

Comment: "Now, let's assume that X={0.5,2,2.5,⋯,3.23} where 3.23 is the largest value in the set"  If $3.23$ is the largest value in the set the $3.23 = \sup X$ and you are done.  The only issue is when you have a bounded set that *doesn't* have a largest value.  (For example all the elements are less than $6.2$ but $6.2$ is not in the set and there is no element that is largest in the set).

Comment: @fleablood I provided the link for the book where the proof is presented. As far as I understand, the proof should hold for any $x \in X$ meaning that if you pick $3.23$, you're right, we are done, but what if I select a different $x$?

Comment: By the way, you should indicate *in your post* that you are talking about specifically the book by Hubbard, and you are specifically talking about *that* proof, and you should *include* the proof as part of your post.

Comment: I do admit I was assuming the book you were using was using a more sophisticated definition of the reals.  I suppose the definition of the reals as numbers with infinite length decimal places (assuming you know what that means and makes sense) is okay. But if so, then the proof that every bounded set has a $\sup$ would be that for any precision value of $10^{-k}$ there will always be a number $b_k$ with $k$ decimal places where $b^k \le $ some element in $X$ and $b^k + 10^{k+1} > $ all elements in $X$.  Then the infinite decimal $b_\infty$ created this way is the $\sup X$.  This is... okay but

Comment: ... I feel it makes a lot of assumptions and assumes many things or more well defined then they actually are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the proof in Hubbard and your example.

$x = 2$ and $a = 6.2$.  $2 < 6$ so the first set to consider is $\{2,3,4, 5,6\}$.

$4$ is an upper bound of $x$ but $2,3$ are not.  So so $b_0 =3$ which is the largest that is not an upper bound.

$j= 1$ and we consider all the numbers between $b_0 = 3$ and $a = 6.2$ with one decimal where we consider $j=1$ decimal point.  That set is $\{2.1,2.2,2.3,........., 6.0,6.1,6.2\}$.

$3.3$ is an upper bound of $X$ but $3.2$ is not.  So $b_1 = 3.2$.

Now for $j = 2$ we consider all the numbers between $3.2$ and $6.2$ with two decimals.  That set is $\{3.20,3.21,3.22,...........6.19,6.20\}$.  Now $3.23$ is an upper bound but $3.22$ is not.  So $b_2 =3.22$.

So consider $3$ decimals $3.220,......., 6.199, 6.200$ and get $b_3 = 3.229$.

Then for we consider $3.290,3.291, ....., 6.1999, 6.20$ and $b_4 = 3.299$ and so on $b_5 = 3.2999$ ....And $\sup X$ is $3.22999999999....... = 3.23$

Answer (score 2):

You're approaching this the wrong way.

In fact, the first digit of $x$ which is smaller than a digit of $\alpha$ might occur before the decimal place.

Consider the numbers $21.\overline{1}$ and $12.\overline{2}$. The only place where $12.\overline{2}$ has a smaller value than $21.\overline{1}$ is the tens place, where $j = -1$.

In the case you presented, it's the ones place digit. So $j = 0$.

Thus, we start out with $b_j = 3$.

We then get $b_{j + 1} = 3.2$.

We then get $b_{j + 2} = 3.22$.

We hten get $b_{j + 3} = 3.229$.

In general, we have $b_{j + 2 + n}$ is the decimal beginning with $3.22$ and followed by $n$ copies of $9$.

Taking the infinite digit string gives us $3.22\overline{9} = 3.23$ as required.

Comment: How do we proceed with the case where $j=-1$?

Comment: @whitepanda In exactly the same way that we would proceed in the case that $j \neq -1$. There's nothing special about that value of $j$.

Comment: I was asking this since the proof states "...can be written using only j digits after the decimal". I guess j=-1 and j=0 are equal in this case?

Comment: @whitepanda Formally speaking, "$x$ can be written using only $j$ digits after the decimal" can be translated to "$x \cdot 10^j$ is an integer". This allows us to make sense of $j = -1$.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth pointing out that the proof is incorrect because there is no guarantee that $b_j$ exists; there might not be any number in $$S = \{ u: u \in [x,a] \text{ and } u \text{ can be written using only } j \text{ digits after the decimal, then all zeros} \},$$ that is not an upper bound. Consider the case when $X=\{2\}$, $x=2$ and $a=3$, then $S = \{2,3\}$ and only contains upper bounds to $X$. Or when $X$ is the set of all real numbers less than $1$ and $a=10$, then $S = \{10\}$ and again only contains upper bounds.

---

**Edit**: The proof and some terminology is changed in the fifth edition of the book which corrects the proof:

- $[x]_k$ denotes the number formed by keeping all
  digits to the left of and including the $10^k$th position, setting all others to $0$.
- $j$ is the largest integer such that $[x]_j < [a]_j$
- $S$ is defined as all numbers that have the same $k$th digit as $x$ for $k > j$ and that have $0$ as the $k$th digit for $k < j$, that are in $[[x]_j, a]$
- $b_j$ is defined as the largest element in $S$ such that $X \cap [b_j, a] \neq \emptyset$

This ensures $S$ is non-empty and that $b_j$ exists.